# What is the autocorrelation function of a stochastic process evaluated at $t=0$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we have a stochastic process $x(t)$. Define the autocorrelation function (ACF) of this signal as

$$
G(t)= \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \int^T_0 \langle x(\tau)x(\tau+t)\rangle d\tau
$$
My question is: what is the significance of this function evaluated at $t=0$?

My attempts at understanding are below. I understand that setting $t=0$ gives:

$$
G(0)= \lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \int^T_0 \langle x(\tau)^2\rangle d\tau
$$
which looks similar to the variance. Is it the case that $G(0) =\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\langle x(t)^2\rangle$ ? ie. Does $G(0)$ equal the steady state variance of the process?

As an example, I looked at the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, with $\dot{x}(t) =  - a x(t) + D\xi(t)$ where $\xi(t)$ is a Wiener Process. Finding the time-dependent variance of this process gives:
$$
\langle x(t)^2 \rangle = e^{-2at}\langle x(0)^2 \rangle + \frac{D^2}{2a}(1-e^{-2 a t})
$$

For this process, we also get an ACF of:
$$
G(t) = \frac{D^2}{2a}e^{-at}
$$
I notice that, when we take $t\rightarrow 0$, in the ACT this gives the steady state variance of the process $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\langle x(t)^2\rangle$. Is this just a coincidence, or does this apply in general?

Comment: I would call the function $G(t)$ that you defined the autocovariance function, but I am in mathematics. The observation you make is true. G(0) is the variance of the process.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Is there a proof that this holds in general? In particular, that $G(0)$ is the variance as $t$ goes to $\infty$, rather than the variance at any other time.